# select rows based on another query result with rank PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am beginner of SQL language.

I am trying to write a query that gets rows from `words` table based on result of another query (`news` table).

I have the below two tables.

**News**

| id, | url | url_order | source | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | http://.. | 1 | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176+03 |
| 2 | http://.. | 1 | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:12:32.459176+03 |
| 3 | http://.. | 1 | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:11:32.459176+03 |
| 4 | http://.. | 2 | src2 | 2022-02-26 02:10:36.683408+03 |
| 5 | http://.. | 2 | src2 | 2022-02-26 02:09:36.683408+03 |
| 6 | http://.. | 2 | src2 | 2022-02-26 02:08:36.683408+03 |
| 7 | http://.. | 5 | src6 | 2022-02-27 05:47:46.803674+03 |
| 8 | http://.. | 5 | src6 | 2022-02-27 05:46:46.803674+03 |
| 9 | http://.. | 5 | src6 | 2022-02-27 05:45:46.803674+03 |

**Words**

| id, | news_id | word | source | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | foo | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176+03 |
| 2 | 4 | ipsum | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176+03 |
| 3 | 7 | dolor | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176+03 |
| 4 | 8 | sit | src2 | 2022-02-26 02:13:36.683408+03 |
| 5 | 9 | amet | src6 | 2022-02-27 05:47:46.803674+03 |

I'm getting the below result after the following query.

```
SELECT id, url, url_order, created, source
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,url,url_order,created,source,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY url_order, source ORDER BY COALESCE(created) DESC) 
        MyRank  -- Rank each (def, item) combination by "time"
    FROM news
    ) src
WHERE MyRank = 1
AND url_order < 25
```

Result from above query (most recent row each url order)

| id, | url | url_order | source | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | http://.. | 1 | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176+03 |
| 4 | http://.. | 2 | src2 | 2022-02-26 02:10:36.683408+03 |
| 7 | http://.. | 5 | src6 | 2022-02-27 05:47:46.803674+03 |

I want to get related words from words table with news_id which I getting with this SQL query

**expected output**

| id, | news_id | word | source | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | foo | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176+03 |
| 2 | 4 | ipsum | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176+03 |
| 3 | 7 | dolor | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176+03 |

I am getting rows which most recent of each group with above query and I need to get words related with this Id's from another table words

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data in said tables, as well as the expected output of the query?

Comment: Updated!. Just trying to get results from another table with handled query ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. You can simply turn your current query into a subquery for the query against the `Words` table.

```
SELECT *
FROM words
WHERE news_id in (
    SELECT id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            id,url,url_order,created,source,
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY url_order, source ORDER BY COALESCE(created) DESC) 
            MyRank  -- Rank each (def, item) combination by "time"
        FROM news
    ) src
    WHERE MyRank = 1
    AND url_order < 25
)
```

Below is the output from [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ffcc855614273b6f4a7c5120cabde743).

| id | news_id | word | source | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | foo | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176 |
| 2 | 4 | ipsum | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176 |
| 3 | 7 | dolor | src1 | 2022-02-26 02:13:32.459176 |

Comment: Thank you question updated

Comment: I believe this is returning your expect result. Can you confirm?

Comment: I already tried this and others. query returning older data. query must return words which related with first query

Comment: It's returning the same output as what you have listed in your question as the "expected" output. If that is not the expected output, can you update your question with what is the expected output?

Comment: it's looking like you are right but I've 200K+ rows in words table in my local server and when I run this query returning older data than expected also (id) of news autoincrement that means no duplicate. it cant be older data with same news_id

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you beyond the information you have provided here. You'll need to provide more details around the rows coming back wrong, in the original post, for us to be able to provide more help.

Comment: re check my data and found some older data with related query thank you